# invalid flag in #cgo LDFLAGS

Tags: go, cgo

I am using go version go version "go1.14.4 linux/amd64" on ubuntu 18.  This code wasn't written by me, but I believe it worked with a go version a few years older than my current one.  When I try to build, I get this error.  Any ideas what I need to do to fix?

```
go build *.go
go build command-line-arguments: invalid flag in #cgo LDFLAGS: -    I/home/me/myProject/lib
```

Here's what I believe are the relevant bits of my go file:

```
package main
/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -v -I${SRCDIR}/lib -lplaintext
#cgo CFLAGS: -I${SRCDIR}/include -I${SRCDIR}/lib

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "plaintext.h"
*/
import "C"


import (

    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "crypto/md5"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "log/syslog"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
    "unsafe"

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to specify the search path for your library, so you should use `-L`. `-I` is used for the compiler include directories.

```
package main /*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -v -L${SRCDIR}/lib -lplaintext
#cgo CFLAGS: -I${SRCDIR}/include -I${SRCDIR}/lib
```

Comment: That worked - thank you!  This code wasn't written by me and I assume it must have compiled in the past.  However, with your change, this now creates the binary.  Much appreciated!